# How do i get the local storage value in background page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am newbie as far as developing chrome extension is concerned.

I am testing an extension. In this i have a background page and options page. In options page i am storing user entered password in local storage which i want to retrieve in the background page that is on click of browser icon.

My options page is :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Options for Password</title>
<script>
 function savePassword()
  {
 window.localStorage.setItem('password', txtPassword.value);


  }
</script>   
</head>
<body >
<h1>Enter Password</h1>
<input type='password' name='txtPassword' id='txtPassword'/>
<br />
<button onclick='savePassword();'>Save</button>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

And my background page is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert('password from tab:'+window.localStorage.getItem('password'));getfeedback_dialog_submitButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'if(gettext.value==\'"+window.localStorage.getItem(password)'+"\'){document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackcontainer);document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackoverlay);}');"});
});


</script>
</head>
</html>
```

When i save password through options page and then i click on browser action then i am getting the alert **password from tab:null**.

I am confused how to retrieve the value stored in the local storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gets the localStorage value from the page where the browser action is clicked, where it is `null`. Change your quotes to get it at the background page:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert('password from tab:"+window.localStorage.getItem('password')+"');"});
```

Note that this may allow for code injection.

**EDIT**: Do this, it should work as long as your variables are defined properly and `window.localStorage.getItem('password')` is expected to be a string:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert('password from tab:"+window.localStorage.getItem('password')+"');"
+"getfeedback_dialog_submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){if(gettext.value=='"+window.localStorage.getItem('password')+"')"
+"{document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackcontainer);document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackoverlay);}},false);"});
```

I split your code into multiple lines for readability.

Comment: Thanks digital for replying. Can you please help me out i want to test whether the stored value is equal to some text box entered value? I have to test following conditions if(gettext.value==window.localStorage.getItem(password)){document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackcontainer);document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackoverlay);} How can i write this in this code of block?

Comment: @Pankaj Khurana If you are also injecting the code, just do `if(gettext.value==\'"+window.localStorage.getItem(password)'+"\'){...`
But I would recommend an external script with [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: I have used follwing code but nothing is happening am i missing something(no error): getfeedback_dialog_submitButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'if(gettext.value==\'"+window.localStorage.getItem(password)'+"\'){document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackcontainer);document.body.removeChild(getfeedbackoverlay);}');"});

Comment: `onclick` runs in the page's context, not the content scripts's context, and your quotes may not be working. But can you ask this in another question or edit your question?

Comment: i have edited my question and added the code which checks for user input is equal to the stored value

Comment: thanks mr digital for your valuable help. after making changes it started working now :-)